# How to speed up contacts handling in react native when slow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have been working on putting together a module to allow a user to invite their friends to use an app. Code works without major issue, but since I have over 100 contacts in my phone, the speed is rather slow. Scrolling isn't a problem, and I can add a loader as the phone pulls the data. But I when I choose an element for highlight it takes a few seconds for the item to get checked. I'm curious if anyone has any tips for how to optimize?

My snack is below:

https://snack.expo.io/@fauslyfox110/testingreferrals

Main file: inviteScreenTwo.js

Answer (score 1):

React will update the elements on screen whenever you make it change to your state. In your case, I suspect that the delay is due to React going through all the contact records your showing and updating them when you change the highlighting.

One way of dealing with this is to make sure that contacts that are off-screen aren't actually in the DOM. You would need to update your `render` method to place only contact records in the list that are actually visible. That way, React won't need to update as many elements. Please refer to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists) to read more about this optimization.

Another way would be to override the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate` for your record components, making sure that the only rerender when their highlighted status changes. This is called *reconciliation avoidance*. The method has the following signature:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
}
```

By default, this method always returns `true`. You could change it to compare `nextProps` with `this.props`, checking that the highlighting has changed, and return `true` or `false` as appropriate. Read more about this optimization in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation).